# Run custom code when MFC app is terminated: d'tor or WM_CLOSE?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I have a dialog-based MFC application which needs to stop Windows Wifi service in order to run correctly, but I want to enable it again when my application exits.

So I thought I'd put the code that restarts the service in the destructor of the main dialog class.

Now it has come to my attention that others put their code which should be run during program termination into a `WM_CLOSE` message handler.

Both ways seem to work, but I would like to know if there are downsides to either way.

Comment: Well I usually put it in a `WM_DESTROY` handler, but I prefer that to the destructor because I know the MFC infrastructure will still be alive and by the time I get to the dtor, I'm not sure :-) Usually I reserve the dtor for just deleting heap allocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MFC dialog based application you can place finalization code to application class `InitInstance` method, immediately after main dialog `DoModal` call. For other MFC application types (MDI, SDI) finalization code is usually placed to `ExitInstance` method.

The difference between dialog based application and SDI/MDI applications, is that `InitInstance` in dialog based applications returns FALSE, and application exits - all action is done in the main dialog `DoModal` call.

You can prefer to use `ExitInstance` for all application types, it should work as well.

**Edit**. If you want to make cleanup code inside of the dialog class, `WM_DESTROY` (already mentioned by Roger Rowland) is better place than `WM_CLOSE`. Sometimes we can handle `WM_CLOSE` message and prevent a dialog to be closed, for example, by asking "Exit the program? Yes - No". In the case you want to use some child windows, they exist in `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_DESTROY` message handlers, and don't exist in a dialog destructor. Also, message queue doesn't exist when main dialog destructor is called, so you should not use Windows messaging in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Aim to maintain symmetry: if you are stopping the wifi service in a constructor, then restart it in the same class's destructor.  If instead you stop the service in `InitInstance`, you would restart it in `ExitInstance`; if as a response to `WM_CREATE` or some other message, then restart it in `WM_CLOSE`, etc.

Constructors and destructors have no way of returning an error status, so normally they are better suited for simple tasks such as initialization and memory allocation/deallocation.

`InitInstance` and `ExitInstance`, as well as windows messages such as `WM_CLOSE`, happen at a good spot in the application's lifetime to display error messages if necessary, or to abort in response to error conditions.